# Web Worker written in Typescript does not get built/compiled (using vite) into Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, vite, web-worker

I am using a Web Worker in typescript the following way:

```
const url = new URL("src/lib/Functions/CalculateRidge.ts", import.meta.url);
const worker = new Worker(url, { type: 'module' })
```

In development, this work perfectly fine, the worker is loaded from the given url, and the worker executes the function and gives the correct result. But when building, all files get converted to .js except my worker file. Then in deployment (Github Pages) when the same code above is being executed, the url request IS succesful (it finds the file and makes a valid/succesful request for it), but the code fails with the following error message:

"Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "video/mp2t". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."

I believe this error comes because a typescript file (a file with .ts extentions) cannot be executed or read, so i believe the error lays in that the Web Worker typescript file is not being compiled/transformed into Javascript.

This is an image of the distribution/build folder:

[image]

I use "vite build" to build the project and "npx gh-pages -d dist" to deploy the project to Github Pages. The `vite.config.ts` file looks like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'
import path from 'path';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: "/solar-analysis-faroe-island/",
  plugins: [svelte()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: path.resolve('src/'),
    }
  },
})
```

`tsconfig.node.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node"
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

`tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "src/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    /**
     * Typecheck JS in `.svelte` and `.js` files by default.
     * Disable checkJs if you'd like to use dynamic types in JS.
     * Note that setting allowJs false does not prevent the use
     * of JS in `.svelte` files.
     */
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
  "include": ["src/*.ts","src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.svelte"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

And `svelte.config.js` looks like this:

```
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

export default {
  // Consult https://svelte.dev/docs#compile-time-svelte-preprocess
  // for more information about preprocessors
  preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [an open issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/11823) regarding that; a suggested workaround is importing via  with a `?worker&url` query, that would be:

```js
import workerUrl from "src/lib/Functions/CalculateRidge?worker&url";
const worker = new Worker(workerUrl, { type: 'module' })
```

[Relevant docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#import-with-query-suffixes)

Comment: I tried importing the url as you specified, but now i get the following error when deploying:

"Unexpected early exit. This happens when Promises returned by plugins cannot resolve. Unfinished hook action(s) on exit:
(vite:worker) transform "project/location/solar-analysis-faroe-island/src/lib/Functions/CalculateRidge.ts?worker&url"".

Your suggested change still works for development though. What could cause this error? And imports only work at the top-level of the code, right? Because i cannot place the import just above the const worker = ...

Comment: I have unfortunately never seen that error before. And yes, the import should be on the top level, in other places one may use a dynamic import but there is not really any point here as the import just provides a URL (i.e. the import itself does not load a large amount of data that might be worth lazy loading later).

Comment: Well that's no good... do you have any suggestions on how i could work around this error? I see one suggesting installing older versions of rollup, but that did not work for me...

Comment: Have you seen the SvelteKit issue referencing the linked Vite issue? [Here](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/9528#issuecomment-1493912401) is a suggested workaround, if that helps I would add that to the answer while the issue is resolved.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm looking at my problem right now, and i see that i should had mentioned that i keep both the code that creates the worker and the worker itself inside the same script. The reason: so all worker-code is located in one file. I seperated the file, and i believe that solved the issue. But now a new issue regarding GeoTiff.js in build has emerged, i'll open a new issue.

Comment: New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76051452/rollup-build-error-when-including-geotiff-js-and-web-worker-in-build